# Getting item names from Square Connect API

Tags: python, square-connect

[image: What I see on dashboard]

I am wondering how to get this item description / information from transactions on Square. For me, even using:

```
'/v2/locations/{0}/transactions/{1}'.format(LOC_ID, tid)
```

Does not return any item names, instead I get completely anonymous/useless information:

```
 {
  "transaction": {
    "id": "BZDxxxxxx",
    "location_id": "3PBxxxxx",
    "created_at": "2016-10-14T22:55:33Z",
    "tenders": [
      {
        "id": "VJO1rxxxxx",
        "location_id": "3PBxxxx",
        "transaction_id": "BZDxxxxxx",
        "created_at": "2016-10-14T22:55:31Z",
        "amount_money": {
          "amount": 2800,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "processing_fee_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "type": "OTHER"
      }
    ],
    "product": "REGISTER",
    "client_id": "1E7xxxx"
  }
}
```

How do I go from what is returned above to the item name that is shown on the website transaction list?

Comment: Check out our new Orders API for e-commerce itemizations: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/building-for-an-omni-channel-business-with-squares-apis-has-never-been-easier-3b5e0977741a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can itemize your transactions with the [Orders Endpoints](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/building-for-an-omni-channel-business-with-squares-apis-has-never-been-easier-3b5e0977741a) Have you tried using the `/v1/{location_id}/payments` endpoint? You can get some more information about the items there.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#updatingorderstate