# Getting compact information from Square Connect API

Tags: php, api, square-connect

I want to load Transactions with their Items and Customer from [Square Connect API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2) (using [PHP client library](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk)), but Transactions don't contain any link to their Items unless there is order_id which often tends to be null.

As mentioned in [Getting item names from Square Connect API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223762/getting-item-names-from-square-connect-api) I could go back to version 1 of the API and get list of [Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-payments) which includes Items, but there is no connection to Customer.

I know I could join Transactions to Payments by using Tenders which are included in both and get all information I need that way, but it doesn't seem to be good approach (combining two versions of API just seems wrong considering old versions of other APIs tend to deprecate and shut down after some time) and it would be very inefficient for both sides (more requests + downloading duplicate data just to try to match them).

So I would like to know if there's any better way to do this or why isn't.

Comment: you generally have the right idea. At this moment getting all of the data requires multiple API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto on this (I can't comment yet - not enough rep). FreshKDS pull these details from the API (somehow) to display items on their Kitchen Screen. However as I'm already using a cloud service like Zapier (for Woo Orders to Trello Cards) and don't want to have the additional KDS cost as it doesn't pull square orders from WooCommerce (obviously). 
So I need to be able to get the Square POS new order details to also create a Trello card - which I am using as a Kitchen Screen.

In regards to the OP's question: Does anyone have any info about webhooks perhaps, or a way to pull an entire order (even if I have to clone it to a database or cloud based spreadsheet) to allow viewing or iteration of individual food/ drink items?

Cheers.